# Ошибка: ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Есть полностью вновь установленная Docker имидж Oracle 19c.

Подключаюсь коммандой `sqlplus / as sysdba`. После подключения любой запрос выдаёт ошибку, например:

```
SELECT * FROM all_users
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Ну если не доступно, тогда пробую запустить БД:

```
SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initorclcd.ora'
```

Проверяю запущенные процессы:

```
$ ps aux | grep pmon 
oracle      22  0.0  0.2 2028516 66372 ?       Ss   21:52   0:00 ora_pmon_ORCLCDB
oracle    2421  0.0  0.0   9112   852 pts/1    S+   22:47   0:00 grep --color=auto pmon
```

И выглядит, что всё работаеет.

Что тут не так?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [sqlplus :: ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61786322) от участника [@Francesco Mantovani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4652358/francesco-mantovani)</sub>

Comment: ассоциция:https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788697

Answer (score 2):

Образ БД имеет SID `ORCLCDB`, что видно по суфиксу `PMON` процесса.

Но при попытке запустить БД, идёт обращение к файлу инициализации initorclcd.ora, а это заначит, что его поиск был для SID `orclcd`.

Думаю, опечатка при установке переменной окружения `ORACLE_SID`, недoстaет последней "B".

1. проверте, что сейчас установлено: `echo $ORACLE_SID`
2. установите правильно: `export ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB; . oraenv`
3. сделайте установку постоянной: `echo "export ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB; . oraenv" >> ~/.bashrc`

Теперь запустите SQL*Plus и всё должно работать.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788697) от участника [@Connor McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

У Вас не выставлены переменные окружекния

export ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB

export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1

export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle

sqlplus / as sysdba

И работайте на здоровье.

Можно еще проверить содержание файла oratab.

cat etc/oratab

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Переменные окружения были установлены, но одна из них была установленна неверно. На это уже есть ответ. Вы его прочитали?

Comment: У вас есть желание улучшить ответ? В текущем виде он выглядит не очень.